# Failed to load pdf in chrome browser

Tags: pdf

I am getting an error as below,

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8Li7.png)

I am opening pdf file by below link

http://www.satyajainfratech.com/Bliss-web-brochure-landscaped.pdf

code written for the same is

```
<a href="Bliss-web-brochure-landscaped.pdf" target="_blank" class="btn btn-normal" type="application/pdf">Download Brochure</a>
```

Comment: The PDF seems to be broken in some non-obvious way. Have you tried a different PDF?

Comment: Yes i have tried with different file. But getting the same error. and Both pdf working fine in my pc offline.

Comment: All signs point to a broken PDF though.

Comment: @Pekka웃 i will upload pdf again.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF is corrupt, ending in the middle of a stream. The last object starts with

```
10 0 obj^M
<<^M
/Filter [/FlateDecode ]^M
/Length 465325^M
>>^M
stream^M
```

This stream should have 465325 bytes of binary data followed by and `endstream` marker. But the file end abruptly mid-stream after about 43475 bytes of data, with no `endstream` or file trailer.

Answer (score -1):

When I opened it I got this warning in chrome: "/deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details."

If you remove the deprecated combinator it should open normally.